# Options do select não funciona usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Com este select

```html
<label>Quantos módulos fiscais a sua propriedada tem:</label>
<select id="fiscalModule">
  <option value="minifundio">até 1 módulo fiscal</option>
  <option value="small_propertie">maior que 1 e até 2 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="medium_propertie">maior que 2 a até 4 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="secondCategorie_medium_propertie">maior que 4 a até 10 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="bigPropertie">maior que 10 módulos fiscais</option>
</select>
```

Consigo retornar se o valor da primeira opção

> [value = "minifundio"]

foi selecionado:

```js
let fiscalModule = document.querySelector('select[id=fiscalModule]');  
let isMinifundio = fiscalModule.options[fiscalModule.selectedIndex].value == 'minifundio' ? true : false;
```

Entretanto não consigo retornar as demais opções, como

> [value = "bigPropertie"]

Aqui está meu [link para jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilianguimaraes/dqxvanhw/8/)

Comment: Não sei, mas parece que quando vc escolhe o estado, a lista das cidades deve mudar. E não muda. Ao seja, o problema deve ser maior. Pessoalmente, acho bem complicado usar jQuery para isso... Grande clássico das bibliotecas: parece legal, facíl, mas quando inicia a ter problema.... Coloca um alert no submit para ver o conteudo que vc recebe do select.

Comment: Nossa moça, **1°** esse código postado não tem nada de **jQuery**, **2º** claro que só consegue retornar a primeira opção, pois, nessa parte do código  `== 'minifundio' ? true : false;` faz a verificação com a primeira opção somente, como poderia retornar as demais?!!

Comment: querido, é claro que tem mais opções de verificação. obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Para você pegar o valor selecionado basta usar `fiscalModule.value`. E você não precisa de `JQuery` para isso.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
let fiscalModule = document.getElementById('fiscalModule');

fiscalModule.onchange = function(){
  //fiscalModule.value
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<label>Quantos módulos fiscais a sua propriedada tem:</label>
<select id="fiscalModule">
  <option value="minifundio">até 1 módulo fiscal</option>
  <option value="small_propertie">maior que 1 e até 2 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="medium_propertie">maior que 2 a até 4 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="secondCategorie_medium_propertie">maior que 4 a até 10 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="bigPropertie">maior que 10 módulos fiscais</option>
</select>
```

Para realizar uma operação diferente para cada valor você pode fazer um `switch`. Veja o exemplo abaixo usando o código do fiddle que você mandou:

```js
let fiscalModule = document.querySelector('select[id=fiscalModule]');

switch(fiscalModule.value){
  case "minifundio":
    var minifundio = city.num;
    $('#module').val(minifundio);
    $('#dimension').val(minifundio);
    break;
  case "bigPropertie":
    console.log(isBigPropertie, 'isBigPropertie')
    var big_propertie = (city.num * 10)
    $('#module').val(big_propertie);
    $('#propertieClassification').text('grande propriedade rural (latifúndio');
    break;
  case "small_propertie":
    ...
}
```

Comment: Compreendi, Mauro, obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o valor do select com jQuery basta fazer o seguinte:

HTML

```
<label>Quantos módulos fiscais a sua propriedada tem:</label>
<select id="fiscalModule">
  <option value="minifundio">até 1 módulo fiscal</option>
  <option value="small_propertie">maior que 1 e até 2 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="medium_propertie">maior que 2 a até 4 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="secondCategorie_medium_propertie">maior que 4 a até 10 módulos fiscais</option>
  <option value="bigPropertie">maior que 10 módulos fiscais</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

var fiscalModule = $('#fiscalModule').val();